# Sling printing wrong value inside an href

Tags: java, html, aem, sling

I have to show two different banner in two different locations, first one is inside a thank you page and the second one is inside the confirmation email.
In both the case i need to print some info inside the urls.

In the first case the banner is generated by a script where i pass some values using Sling

```
<sly data-sly-use.data="........controller.BookingFormModificaController"></sly>
<sly data-sly-use.booking=".......controller.BookingConferma"></sly>


<div id='b_container'>
<script type = 'text/javascript' id='sp_widget' data-hash='00000' datacontainer='b_container' data-size='1080x500' data-tpncy='false' src='example.com/js/booking_sp_widget.js?checkin=${ data.depDateOld }&checkout=${ data.retDateOld }&iata_orr=1&iata=${ data.arrivalAirport }&lang=${ booking.selectedLanguage }&selected_currency=${ booking.ctx.currency } '></script>
</div>
```

This is the result and is correct:

```
src="http://www.example.com/00000?fid=1540980292381&checkin=2018-12-17&checkout=2018-12-22&iata_orr=1&iata=MXP&lang=it&selected_currency=EUR&dsize=1080,500&dtpncy=false&dtsize=&dmsize="
```

In the second case (the email) is not a script but just an img with an a tag like below

```
<sly data-sly-use.data="........controller.BookingFormModificaController"></sly>
<sly data-sly-use.booking=".......controller.BookingConferma"></sly>

<a href="https://example.com/searchresults.it.html?aid=1503416&checkin=${ data.depDateOld }&checkout=${ data.retDateOld }&iata_orr=1&iata=${ data.arrivalAirport }&lang=${ booking.selectedLanguage }&selected_currency=${ booking.ctx.currency }">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1080x300" width="100%" alt="" style="margin:0; padding:0;border:none;display:block;" />
</a>
```

but in this case, after the email is sent, it has the following url:

```
href="https://example.com/searchresults.it.html?aid=1503416&checkin=&checkout=&iata_orr=1&iata=&lang=&selected_currency="
```

My goal is generate an URL like the first one.

Comment: I am guessing that your controller didn't initialise properly due to which all fields are null in the data and booking objects. Try to print those values outside your img tag and see if they have actual values. If so, please check your logs and see if there was any issue when initialising the sling model/use class. However, I may be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

When attaching queryParameter to a link in HTL/Sightly you can easily use the build in link builder. Simply build a Map in a SlingModel you are good to go.

HTL

```
<a class="a-link" href="${ myModel.linkPath @ extension='json', query=myModel.queryParameterMap }">...</a>
```

Sling Model

```
public static Map<String, String> getQueryParameterMap(final Page currentPage)
{
    final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    if (Objects.nonNull(currentPage))
    {
        map.put("someParameterA", "someValueA");
        map.put("someParameterB", "someValueB");
    }
    return map;
}
```